# Implementação de recyclerView dentro de tabLayout

Tags: android

Gostaria de ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema, sei que pode ser simples para muitos mas para mim ainda é um pouco complicado, então.

Tenho um simples projeto Android com 3 abas, sendo elas 1,2,3. Utilizo um fragmento diferente para cada uma delas, o no fragmento 1 gostaria de implementar uma recyclerView...em qual das classes devo implementar as variáveis de referencia para o RecyclerView? na Main ou na classe do fragmento que desejo que apareça a RecyclerView? Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Tenho a classe Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_padrao);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

Tenho a classe TabFragment

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_itens = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });

        return x;
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
          switch (position){
              case 0 : return new PrimeiroFragmento();
              case 1 : return new SegundoFragmento();
              case 2 : return new TerceiroFragmento();
          }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_itens;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Primeira";
                case 1 :
                    return "Segunda";
                case 2 :
                    return "Terceira";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Classes dos fragmentos

```
  public class PrimeiroFragmento extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primeiro_fragmento,null);

    }

}


public class SegundoFragmento extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.segundo_fragmento,null);
    }
}



public class TerceiroFragmento extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.terceiro_fragmento,null);
    }
}
```

Agora aqui tenho a classe modelo para recyclerView

```
public class Dataprovider {

    public Dataprovider(int img_res, String f_name, String quant_de_mensagem){
        this.setImg_res(img_res);
        this.setQuant_de_mensagem(quant_de_mensagem);
        this.setF_name(f_name);

    }
    private int img_res;
    private String f_name, quant_de_mensagem;

    public void setImg_res(int img_res) {
        this.img_res = img_res;
    }

    public int getImg_res() {
        return img_res;
    }

    public String getF_name() {
        return f_name;
    }

    public String getQuant_de_mensagem() {
        return quant_de_mensagem;
    }

    public void setF_name(String f_name) {
        this.f_name = f_name;
    }

    public void setQuant_de_mensagem(String quant_de_mensagem) {
        this.quant_de_mensagem = quant_de_mensagem;
    }
}
```

e por fim o adaptador.

```
public class ReclyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReclyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHorder>{

    private ArrayList<Dataprovider> arrayList = new ArrayList<Dataprovider>();

    public ReclyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Dataprovider> arrayList){

        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHorder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewHorder recyclerViewHorder = new RecyclerViewHorder(view);
        return recyclerViewHorder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHorder holder, int position) {
        Dataprovider dataprovider = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(dataprovider.getImg_res());
        holder.f_name.setText(dataprovider.getF_name());
        holder.quant_de_mensagem.setText(dataprovider.getQuant_de_mensagem());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHorder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView f_name, quant_de_mensagem;


        public RecyclerViewHorder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            f_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.f_name);
            quant_de_mensagem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.quant_de_mensagem);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `recyclerView` deve ser adicionado na View em que você irá exibir. Como você irá exibir um dos 3 fragmentos, então você deverá adicionar o `recyclerview` em um desses 3. O mesmo principio funciona para os componentes. Você sempre deve adicionar um componente ( um botão por exemplo ) na tela que você gostaria de mostrar/ usar.

Comment: Obrigado, por tentar ajudar. Concordo com sua descrição mas minha dúvida é em relação a implementação do código em java, ele vai na classe Main ou na classe do fragmento onde gostaria de mostrar o RecyclerView?

Comment: Vamos lá, activities e fragments possuem um layout. Você só pode referenciar um componente que exista nesse layout que você setou. No caso da activity o layout é passado no setContentView dentro do método onCreate(). Já no fragment isso ocorre no onCreateView(). No seu caso você deve adicionar ao fragment.

Comment: Obrigado vou ver se consigo.

Comment: Não consigo implementar os códigos que tratam o funcionamento da classe RecyclerView.

Comment: Na classe do fragmento, declarei e iniciei as variáveis que tratam o recyclerView

Comment: RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    String [] quant_de_mensagem, f_name;
    int [] img_res = {R.drawable.cbjr};
    ArrayList<Dataprovider> arrayList = new ArrayList<Dataprovider>();

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jcaiqueoliveira/d13d0e6965a1717d7a27

Comment: Wlw parceiro, vou mandar um exemplo pro github

Comment: Cara meu irmão tu é foda msm obrigadão!!! olha o erro, tava retornando return inflater.inflate(R.layout.segundo_fragmento,null);

Comment: Agora tenho outro problema ao testar o app a lista demora para aparecer e quando aparece, se eu girar o aparelho pra formo horizontal a lista some e demora retornar. ..tem alguma dica?

Comment: ao girar o dispositivo ele redesenha as telas. Sobre a lentidão faça uma outra pergunta que isso já foge do escopo da dúvida inicial

Comment: Ta msm assim obrigado.